# What is the name of the era for Queen Elizabeth II?

Tags: neologisms

Given the [Elizabethan era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabethan_era) and the [Victorian era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victorian_era), and the duration of [Queen Elizabeth II's reign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_II#Diamond_Jubilee_and_beyond) of Great Britain, it seems likely that there will be an era named for her.

What is that name? Is there a protocol for such a thing?

Comment: I have heard it described as *The second Elizabethan age*. But we may not know the answer to this question until several more decades have passed. It would be interesting to discover when *the Victorian age*, or *Victorian* in general began to be used. I doubt that it was before the reign of George V, which began in 1910. Does anyone know?

Comment: At the risk of being clapped in the tower for *lese-majesty*, I don't think Brenda has actually *influenced* her subjects/society anything like as much as her illustrious predecessors. Increasingly, her role is just "titular", but although she represents Britain (and the Commonwealth) *while she's on the throne*, I doubt future historians will find her a useful "anchor point" for identifying an "era". As things are shaping up, I think we'll be calling it the **IT era** (or maybe the **Pre-Climate Collapse Era** if it all goes horribly wrong).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think her reign will eventually be seen, at least in Britain, as meriting a name of some sort. (Wait till you see what comes in her wake before making too many judgements about her). But internationally historians will need to attach a name to the period 1945 to 1990. I am not sure that *the Cold War Age* really cuts the mustard.

Comment: @WS2: I'm not saying the period 1953 to (2030? 2040?) won't be seen as significant in the future. But it's not really *the Queen's* era, because she doesn't influence social or political history in the same way as Elizabeth I or Victoria. That latter being followed by the Edwardian period, which  probably represents the swan song for "eras" named after monarchs.

Comment: @FumbleFingers better get her publicists to work on it now or we'll be stuck with the Beatrician era. We can't let that happen.

Comment: @Mitch: I think her PR department already played a blinder by getting her to "participate" in the opening of the Olympics. But we already have meaningful terms suitable for use by present/future historians (**Post WWII, Post-colonial,** etc.). It just seems unlikely a handle based on **"ER" indoors** will ever catch on - she's just *very* "au courant" today because we're all aware she's become our longest-reigning monarch.

Comment: Perhaps the "increasingly-irrelevant-era"?  Oops, did my political skirts just show?

Comment: To add to @FumbleFingers' fine comments: the 19th century was dominated by Britain, so it makes sense that such a long British reign named the era. Britain is now just another European country (whatever many of our politicians pretend) so 'Brenda' is unlikely to give her name to the years beginning 1953.

Comment: @David Garner: Perhaps we should start calling it the ***Brendan Era*** to avoid possible confusion with her illustrious predecessor. (Unless [my favourite Guardian crossword compiler](http://www.theguardian.com/profile/brendan) already has dibs on that one! :)

Comment: Nice idea, +1 @FumbleFingers!

Comment: @David Garner: My favourite crossword of all time is [this one by Brendan](http://image.guardian.co.uk/sys-files/Guardian/documents/2008/10/15/xwMain1610_24521.pdf), where practically every clue/answer puns on **I** (incl. homophonic *eye, ai*, etc.). But she being Queen and all that, I guess if Brenda *('ER indoors! :)* compiled something similar, she'd have to work a lot harder to get that many puns on *the royal **We**.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thanks for that. I'll look at the crossword when I'm back from holiday and have something bigger than an iPhone.

Comment: As Chou En-Lai was supposed to have famously said in answer to a question as to what he thought of the French Revolution - "It's too early to tell."  But far from pandering to the perception that the Chinese regard all of Western Civilization as a 'blip' (actually I understand they scarcely regard us at all), it's almost certain that Chou misunderstood the questioner to be referring to the 1968 riots then happening in Paris.  But as others have pointed out, Royalty no longer shapes history or has any entitlement to lend its name to it.  Pre-neodeluvian in time perhaps, as @FumbleFingers says..

Comment: @JohnMack, Speaking of opinions of Western Civilization, we must mention Gandhi's: I think it would be a good idea.